# Base64Encoder cuts off last 4 characters of string

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, base64

**Edit** Completely changed question after finding that the problem was elsewhere in the application.

I am working on a Heroku client in Flex and am trying to build the authentication tool now.  Heroku uses Basic HTTP Authentication so I setup my User class to store an email and password and expose a method that will return the base64 encoded string representation of the email and password seperated by a colon.  The encoder, however, cuts off the last 4 characters in the string (tested by encoding the same string through the openssl encoder built into *Nix.  The code that I am using to encode the values is as follows:

```
public function getAuthString():String{
    var encoder:Base64Encoder = new Base64Encoder();
    encoder.insertNewLines = false;
    encoder.encode(email + ':' + password);
    trace(email + ':' + password);
    trace(encoder.toString());
    return encoder.toString();
}
```

The trace of the email and password together is correct, but the `encoder.toString()` call returns a string that is short 4 characters (45 characters long instead of 49).

Has anyone else run into this problem before?  If so how did you fix it?

Comment: This is a flex mobile application and it only appears to happen in the emulator.  The device seems to handle things just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActionScript implementation is working as expected.  The openssl implementation has the assumption of a newline.  The extra four characters you are seeing are the newline character.

Comment: Oh okay.  When I run the code in the Flash Builder emulator, I login and then it pops up with a popup (not flash) asking for username and password.  When I run the code on an actual device it doesn't come up at all.  Is this just a feature of flash builder to hide usernames and passwords or something else?